# Angular HttpClient-subscribe select property from data

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm really sure about, that this question is answered multiple times in here. But I can't find them/don't knwo which terms to search for.

I've got a JSON-file looking like that:

```
{
  "pages": [{
      "displayname": "PageA",
      "url": "http://google.de",
      "icon": "iconZ"
    },

    {
      "displayname": "PageB",
      "url": "http://www.pageb.co.uk",
      "icon": "iconY"
    }
  ],
  "icons": [{
      "alias": "iconZ",
      "filename": "iconZ.svg"
    },

    {
      "alias": "iconY",
      "filename": "iconY.svg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I'm using the HttpClient (here called httpService) to get the data from the file.

```
this.httpService.get('./assets/pageconfig.json').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.arrAdress = data as string[];
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    );
```

I want to use the content of pages in my ngFor in the Frontend and I want to get an array of the icon-content for use in the Backend. How can I select/split the data by using the properties.

Thanks for your help
Elias

Comment: What is the value obtained in arrAdress variable?

Comment: What does `data` look like? Does it contains the entire pageconfig.json correctly?

Comment: @Kapcash 
 `Object {pages: Array(6), icons: Array(5)}
[[StableObjectId]]:2
icons:Array(5) [Object, Object, Object, …]
pages:Array(6) [Object, Object, Object, …]
__proto__:Object {constructor: , __defineGetter__: , __defineSetter__: , …}` 
this is how data looks like. Yes it contains the entire pageconfig.json correctly. Sry about that bad formatting, I'm new in that community...

Comment: @Arcteezy `arrAdress` is a string array. But after assigning the value is undefined. Don't know why. Before I just had an array of the obects in the pages-object in my JSON file and everything worked fine.

Comment: Can you iterate over this.arrAdress.pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your `pageconfig.json` is used in both front and backend, and that you just need the "pages" attribute in your angular app, you may get it this way:

```
this.httpService.get('./assets/pageconfig.json').subscribe(
  data => {
    this.arrAdress = data.pages;
  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
);
```

You don't need to cast the data type.

You could also use the rxjs observable map chaining to parse your data and get only what interests you:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.httpService.get('./assets/pageconfig.json')
  .pipe(map(data => data.pages))
  .subscribe(pages=> {
    this.arrAdress = pages;
  }.catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: My get() doesn't know a method called then().

Comment: Well, yes sorry. I confused angularjs and Angular 2+. I just edited my answer!

Comment: I used your first approach. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Need to remove string[], instead use Array of object or any.

```
this.httpService.get('./assets/pageconfig.json').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.arrAdress = data;
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    );



sendData(icon){
    const matched = this.arrAdress.icons.filter(iconObj => iconObj.alias === icon);
    console.log(matched);
  }

 **Template:**

  <div *ngFor="let adress of arrAdress?.pages;" (click)="sendData(adress.icon)">
    <span>{{adress.displayname}}</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: The ngFor-part works. But however I get the following error in my *.html-file:
"Cannot read property 'pages' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions here to solve this issue

Suppose `httpClient.Delete()` option returns back you an `observable` object with `employeeId` as property in it.

Solution 1 (example)

Create an local variable and assign data to it using let statement `(e.g. let response: any = data;).`

```
delete(employee: any) {
    this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(employee.id)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                let response: any = data;
                // now you can use response.employeeId
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error)
            },
            () => {
                console.log("The operation has been completed")
            }
        );
}
```

Solution 2 (example)

Assign type any `(e.g. (data : any)` to received response

```
delete(employee: any) {
    this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(employee.id)
        .subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
             // now you can use data.employeeId
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error)
            },
            () => {
                console.log("The operation has been completed")
            }
        );
}
```